# Bootstrap pills / tabs & dropdowns. An unhappy marriage?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So the Bootstrap documentation describes pills with dropdowns and pills as tab bars, but can the two be combined? Ideally I'd like to have a pill-style navbar of sections, dropping down to the specific items. When the item is chosen, the tab content should change and the section pill become active. However, with what I've attempted so far, the tab content doesn't change and it's the specific menu item that highlights (and doesn't turn off). Either I've got the markup horribly wrong, or I'm trying to combine two parts of Bootstrap that don't play nice together.

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/63kLm/

```
<div class="well">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="pill">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="pill">Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="pill">Item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="pill">Item 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="pill">Item 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#tab6" data-toggle="pill">Item 6</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab7" data-toggle="pill">Item 7</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab8" data-toggle="pill">Item 8</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#tab9" data-toggle="pill">Item 9</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab10" data-toggle="pill">Item 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="#tab1">
        <h3>Default Item 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab2">
        <h3>Item 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab3">
        <h3>Item 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab4">
        <h3>Item 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab5">
        <h3>Item 5</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab6">
        <h3>Item 6</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab7">
        <h3>Item 7</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab8">
        <h3>Item 8</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab9">
        <h3>Item 9</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab10">
        <h3>Item 10</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you make this in [Bootply](http://bootply.com/new) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated my answer with fully working code that includes ids to make the active class function properly.
Here is a Bootply http://www.bootply.com/114915
Also, the Bootstrap documentation has a helpful example, I missed this the first time through.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

```
<div class="well">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="pill">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="pill">Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="pill">Item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="pill">Item 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="pill">Item 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="myTabDrop2" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#tab6" data-toggle="pill">Item 6</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab7" data-toggle="pill">Item 7</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab8" data-toggle="pill">Item 8</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="myTabDrop3" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#tab9" data-toggle="pill">Item 9</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab10" data-toggle="pill">Item 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <h3>Default Item 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <h3>Item 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <h3>Item 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
        <h3>Item 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
        <h3>Item 5</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
        <h3>Item 6</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">
        <h3>Item 7</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab8">
        <h3>Item 8</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab9">
        <h3>Item 9</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab10">
        <h3>Item 10</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```